# popup menu Opens the cursor

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

Help me to make a popup menu. I can't do it. I don't have time to hover over the menu and it disappears. I have already tried everything, the cursor disappears. It should open and close when hovering when the cursor is outside of these elements

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  <style>
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.button-drop {
    background-color: #0ff;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.thisDropDown {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate(0, -8px);
    transition: .3s all;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8rem;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05), 0 -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .04), 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05), 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

.thisDropDown.active {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.thisDropDownSelect {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 20px;
}

a {
    color: aliceblue;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <header class="header container">
        <div><a href="">LOGO</a></div>
        <div class="drop-down" @mouseenter="openDropdown" @mouseleave="closeDropdown">
            <span class="button-drop">Open Menu</span>
            <div class="thisDropDown container" :class="{ active: isDropdownOpen }">
                <div class="thisDropDownSection">
                    <div class="thisDropDownSelect">
                        <span class="thisDropDownTit">Menu 1</span>
                        <span class="thisDropDownTit">Menu 2</span>
                        <span class="thisDropDownTit">Menu 3</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
  </div>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        isDropdownOpen: false
      },
      methods: {
        openDropdown() {
          this.isDropdownOpen = true;
        },
        closeDropdown() {
          this.isDropdownOpen = false;
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice the menu closes when I try to hover over it.
how can I make this situation right?

Answer (score 0):

It hides because the dropdown is contained in the `div` which is listening for the mouse event. Mousing over the drop-down would fire the mouse event again. You can make a toggle using `@mouseOver`, or handle some other mouse event to manage closing it, whichever your desired effect.

In this snippet, I've moved the drop-down out of the div where `button-drop` is. I've also changed the `@mouseEnter` and `@mouseLeave` to just `@mouseOver`, and used the event to call `toggleDropDown()`. `toggleDropDown()` simply inverts the boolean.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  <style>
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.button-drop {
    background-color: #0ff;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.thisDropDown {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate(0, -8px);
    transition: .3s all;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8rem;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05), 0 -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .04), 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05), 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

.thisDropDown.active {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.thisDropDownSelect {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 20px;
}

a {
    color: aliceblue;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <header class="header container">
        <div><a href="">LOGO</a></div>
        <div class="drop-down" @mouseover="toggleDropDown">
            <span class="button-drop">Open Menu</span>
            
        </div>
        <div class="thisDropDown container" :class="{ active: isDropdownOpen }">
            <div class="thisDropDownSection">
                <div class="thisDropDownSelect">
                    <span class="thisDropDownTit">Menu 1</span>
                    <span class="thisDropDownTit">Menu 2</span>
                    <span class="thisDropDownTit">Menu 3</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
  </div>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        isDropdownOpen: false
      },
      methods: {
        toggleDropDown() {
          this.isDropdownOpen = !this.isDropdownOpen;
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how can I make it close when the cursor is outside the elements?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve a result like this: (untitledui.com)
They have a large menu open when you hover over them and if the cursor is outside of these items it automatically closes.